# Publish timeout in Windows Azure on VS 2012

Tags: asp.net, azure, visual-studio-2012

Website publish to Windows Azure from VS 2012 is throwing an error

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web
---------------------------
Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://waws-prod-hk1-001.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net/msdeploy.axd?site=approck'. The operation has timed out
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I think some config file is needed to update `<servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />` value. But dont know which exe is running for publish wizard.  Does anyone faced this issue?

Comment: Is your website in W. Europe? There was a service disruption for Web Sites in West Europe Data Center, as seen in the [Service Dashboard](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/) history. Looks like it was resolved a short time ago.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Nope. It is Hosted in East Asia.